# WPF binding with .NET object not communicating the data

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am following a tutorial on WPF data binding.  I am trying to bind to a .NET object's property to a XAML control but the control does not display the expected data.  These are what I believe to be the relevant sections of code:

In procedural code: (Note: removed ObservableCollection in PhotoGallery after original post)

```
Namespace PhotoGallery
Partial Public Class MainWindow
  Inherits Window
  Private photos As New Photos
  ...
End Class

Namespace PhotoGallery
Public Class Photos
  Inherits Collection(Of Photo)
  ...
End Class
```

In XAML (Solution/Project name is Ch13-PhotoGallery):

```
<Window x:Class="PhotoGallery.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ch13_PhotoGallery.PhotoGallery"
    ...>

<Window.Resources>
  <local:Photos x:Key="Photos"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And this is the control that is not displaying the data, which is the size of the Photos collection:

```
<Label x:Name="numItemsLabel" Background="AliceBlue" FontSize="8" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Photos}, Path=Count}"/>
```

When I typed in the < Label >, Intellisense popped up 'Count' for the Path property, so I think that tells me I have everything defined correctly.

If I add this line of procedural code behind to the refresh() method:

```
numItemsLabel.Content = photos.Count
```

Then the count is displayed correctly.

But I'm not getting the binding in XAML to display Photos.Count.

Comment: is `photos` the same object as `<local:Photos x:Key="Photos"/>`?

Comment: Yes it is, and I thought I had all the capitalization consistent, but your question caused me to notice I had declared 'photos' in the MainWindow class not capitalized.  So I changed it to 'Photos', but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: "Yes it is" -- no, it isn't. It's a completely different object. What are you doing to populate the instance of `Photos` that you created as a resource? Did you know that you were creating two completely different instances of `Photos`, or did you think that something in the framework would associate the two, somehow?

Comment: I think what you probably want to do is basically what Salvador tells you in his answer. You only want one instance of `Photos`, and it should be a public property (with a get/set) of your viewmodel. Get to it by binding, not as a StaticResource.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Your 1st response above seems pretty important; you are right, I don't understand that I am creating 2 different instances, so I guess didn't think about them needing to be associated.  I thought procedural code objects are accessible in XAML, the point of the Resources decl.  To answer your other question, Photos is populated in the procedural code.  Again, this is an exercise that builds up to a completely different project at the end, but at this point Binding is the topic, so things are done in an elemental way to demonstrate WPF workings. Are code objects not XAML accessible?

Comment: @Alan The mechanism for XAML access to C# stuff is: Write a viewmodel, assign to the DataContext, and use `Binding` -- as shown in Salvador's answer. The elemental way to demonstrate bindings is with a viewmodel.

Comment: When you create a resource as you did in the XAML with that `Photos` object, you created an instance of `Photos` that objects in the XAML can use via the `StaticResource` thing. Some of your C# code can get to it as well, but that's a weird way to do stuff. Also: If the tutorial told you to write a subclass of `ObservableCollection`, it is a bad tutorial written by a clueless person. That subclass is pointless. Don't take my word for it -- ask another question: "My tutorial said do this; some random ranty dude says I shouldn't. Who do I trust?"

Comment: Thanks, & I will get to ViewModel obviously because MVVM is a fundamental way to architect many applications.  But just as you were composing your comment, I was discovering that DataContext is in fact my issue.  I will update my post after some more research, but when I added `Me.DataContext = Photos`, and changed the XAML controls Content property to `{Binding Path=Count}` the Photos.Count showed up.  DataContext hadn't yet been covered in the tutorial so I don't think this is the solution being taught at this point, but it's a start.

Comment: Sorry, the ObservableCollection declaration above was an oversight on my part; that's for the next topic, not this topic.  I obviously need a little more work on StaticResources as well.  I didn't know that about what was being created regards the .NET object I was trying to connect with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140196/discussion-between-alan-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: @EdPlunkett I did finally work on the ViewModel code as you suggested, but I've had some problems if you wouldn't mind looking at this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686740/inotifypropertychanged-not-causing-screen-update-in-this-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a *new instance* of the `Photos` class:

```
<local:Photos x:Key="Photos"/>
```

If you want to bind to the `Photos` collection that you have created in your `MainWindow.xaml.vb` file you should expose it as a *public property* - you can only bind to properties but not fields - and set the `DataContext` of the window to an instance of the class where this property is defined, i.e. the window class itself in your case:

```
Class MainWindow
    Public Property Photos As Photos

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        DataContext = Me
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can the *bind* directly to the property:

```
<Label x:Name="numItemsLabel" Background="AliceBlue" FontSize="8" Content="{Binding Path=Photos.Count}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel needs to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, this will let your window listen to changes to your ViewModel

Here's an example of how to implement this interface in VB
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7de44362-8b88-4292-b4ee-0385c3b34d7d/im-just-looking-for-a-simple-vb-net-mvvm-sample-wpf?forum=wpf

ViewModel

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Sub New()
        Me.myTextValue = "default value..."
    End Sub

    Private myTextValue As String = String.Empty
    Public Property MyTextProperty() As String
        Get
            Return Me.myTextValue
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.myTextValue = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyTextProperty")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

End Class
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML Code Behind

```
Class MainWindow 
    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.DataContext = New ViewModel()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It will take me a bit to code up a ViewModel, which I will do.  But, the tutorial I'm using doesn't use a ViewModel for this project.  But I believe you are pointing me in the right direction with INotifyPropertyChanged.  That is mentioned in the tutorial, but not at the point of this exercise to bind to the .NET object.  Never the less, where could I place INotifyPropertyChanged if I'm not using a ViewModel? Also, I searched the finished solution and didn't find INotifyPropertyChanged in the project.  And obviously I haven't been able to decipher my problem from the solution.

Comment: @Alan I'd take Salvador's advice and just write a viewmodel. As you can see from his example, it's not a great deal of work. Speaking from years of pro WPF experience, any tutorial that doesn't start with creating a viewmodel is worthless.

Comment: Will do.  For the record, this particular tutorial is not focused on project architecture, but rather the nuts and bolts of WPF operations.

Comment: So I finally got around to using your code. I had problems.   It is posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686740/inotifypropertychanged-not-causing-screen-update-in-this-code

Comment: The code above was very helpful to resolve this problem, although it is important to point out there was one oversight in the Code Behind listing above.  `Me.DataContext = New ViewModel()` needs to be `Me.DataContext = vm` with the accompanying declaration `Private vm = New ViewModel`.  After that, it works perfectly.  Thx again for the example.