# INotifyPropertyChanged not causing screen update in this code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

The code below is based off of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281844/wpf-binding-with-net-object-not-communicating-the-data):

My problem: I can't see what I'm doing wrong to get INotifyPropertyChanged to cause the textBox1 binding to automatically reflect changes in this simple example.

XAML.  I added textBox2 to confirm the property was changing

```
<StackPanel>
  <Button Margin="25" Content="Change the Value" Click="Button_Click"/>

  <Label Content="{}{Binding MyTextProperty}"/>
  <TextBox Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}"/>

  <Label Content="updated using code behind"/>
  <TextBox Name="textBox2" />
</StackPanel>
```

CodeBehind

```
Partial Class MainWindow

  Private vm = New ViewModel

  Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    DataContext = New ViewModel()
    textBox2.Text = vm.MyTextProperty
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    vm.ChangeTextValue()
    textBox2.Text = vm.MyTextProperty
  End Sub
End Class
```

ViewModel

```
Public Class ViewModel
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Private _MyTextValue As String = String.Empty
  Public Property MyTextProperty() As String
    Get
      Return _MyTextValue
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
      _MyTextValue = value
      NotifyPropertyChanged("MyTextProperty")
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Sub New()
    MyTextProperty = "Value 0"
  End Sub

  Public Sub ChangeTextValue()
    MyTextProperty = Split(MyTextProperty)(0) & " " & Split(MyTextProperty)(1) + 1
  End Sub

  Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

  Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
  End Sub
End Class
```

Aside from whatever mistake I'm making, any other comments about anything written that would be improved by a best practice, please advise; such as declaring the ViewModel or setting up the StaticResource.  I am learning WPF and MVVM as the same time right now.

Comment: What are the extra curly braces for? `<Label Content="{}{Binding MyTextProperty}"/>`

Comment: @EdPlunkett The escape sequence just to be able to show the braces of the binding.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I think Felix has your answer below, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't setting the data context to the correct `ViewModel`

```
DataContext = New ViewModel()
```

Should be:

```
DataContext = vm
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Finally.  I've been having trouble visualizing the setting of the data context and window resources, so that was a great help.  Even though it was so simple, I would have never found that.